# How to write lambda function with three conditions

Tags: python, if-statement, lambda

I want to write a function that gives returns 3 if x>y returns 1 if x==0 and returns 0 if x

```
def make_points():
    return lambda x,y: 3 if x>y else 0
```

I tried this but I want to add another condition.

Comment: Maybe a lambda isn't the right choice here? Perhaps define a proper function which can be nicely formatted using actual `if` statements, and return that?

Comment: Do you *really* want a function which returns a new function each time you call it? If so, *why* do you want that?

Comment: You are right I do not need a function that returns a new function. I did not know that you can just save the lambda function in the variable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> returns 3 if x>y returns 1 if x==0 and returns 0 if x

You can basically write that as you described:

```
lambda x,y: 3 if x>y else 1 if x==0 else 0
```

Comment: THank you. The only correction is that the second condition should be 0 if x < y else 1

Comment: @BorutFlis I am going by what your question actually asks for.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need a lambda; there is nothing wrong with:

```
def make_points(x, y):
    if x == 0:
        return 1
    if x > y:
        return 3
    return 0
```

Which I think is much clearer.